# Method For Opening/Showing Images In A Window in Python 3.6

Tags: image, python-3.x

Today I encountered the problem of that I cannot find a way to use/show images in Python 3.6. Can anyone help me?

If you need more information, I am basically trying to be able to open several images (and change them, and move them, etc.) in a window (also need to know how to do this). I am trying to make a simple card game test and I want the cards to show up.

Thank you to all who can help me as I journey through this issue.

PLEASE DO NOTE: I am on a Mac.

**EDIT**

I did some research with Tkinter, and came up with this:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Test')
canvas = Canvas(window, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()
image = PhotoImage(file='Users\\school\\Documents\\Python 
Projects\\Images test\\myimage.gif')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image=image)
```

But when I run it I get the error of "`no such file or directory`"

Comment: Dang, no body will help me? I guess it is Easter but still. I expected an answer pretty quick based off of previous experience xD. I will wait though.

Comment: Honestly, from your question, it doesn't look like you tried very hard to find an answer yourself, so people don't want to spend their time when you're not willing to spend your time. Check out the tkinter package: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html and look for other answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=display+image+in+Python+tkinter. If these don't help, then you need to put more information in your question.

Comment: +PurpleDiane Thank you for being honest, and I actually appreciate it. I did do some research while waiting for an answer. I did find some things about Tkinter, and I came up with the edits I am about to make to this question. If you could look it over, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, my guess is that you need to change the file descriptor to `'C:\\Users\\school\\Documents\\Python Projects\\Images test\\myimage.gif'`.

Comment: It wasn't on Windows, but on Mac. Thank you though. Also if it is in the same directory as the .py file, I don't need to use all the directory location.